Issues with Qt creator recognizing the remote device and deploying
The device was set up correctly with the IP and other information, and SSH is active.
When I click to deploy "hammer + green button" the remote device is marked as disconnect and many issues are printed on the screen, giving the impression that the SDK is not configured right. Which doesn't make sense, 'cause I used an SDK compatible with my module (IMX6ULL).
REMOTE DEVICE: Iris Carrier Board (Colibri IMX6ULL).
The following issues are below.
:-1: error: Failed to create directory "device://{0d386063-ec7a-41b1-b536-c13d6bc6ebee}/opt/teste/bin".
/home/user/qtProjects/test/main.cpp:1: error: In included file: 'QtWidgets/qtwidgetsglobal.h' file not found
/home/user/qtProjects/test/main.cpp:7: error: Variable has incomplete type 'QApplication'
/home/user/qtProjects/test/main.cpp:8: error: Variable of type 'MainWindow' has private destructor
/home/user/qtProjects/test/main.cpp:9: error: No member named 'show' in 'MainWindow'
Compile Output:
17:13:39: Failed to create directory "device://{0d386063-ec7a-41b1-b536-c13d6bc6ebee}/opt/test/bin".
17:13:39: Deploy step failed.
Error while building/deploying project test (kit: IMX6ULL)
When executing step "Deploy files"
I tried to add some paths into the "test.pro" file to ensure that Qt selects the right ones for my project, but it didn't work.
INCLUDEPATH += /opt/tdx-xwayland-upstream/6.3.0/sysroots/x86_64-tdxsdk-linux/usr/include
LIBS += /opt/tdx-xwayland-upstream/6.3.0/sysroots/x86_64-tdxsdk-linux/lib
QMAKE_CC = /opt/tdx-xwayland-upstream/6.3.0/sysroots/x86_64-tdxsdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-tdx-linux-gnueabi/arm-tdx-linux-gnueabi-gcc
QMAKE_CXX = /opt/tdx-xwayland-upstream/6.3.0/sysroots/x86_64-tdxsdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-tdx-linux-gnueabi/arm-tdx-linux-gnueabi-g++
QMAKE_LINK = /opt/tdx-xwayland-upstQMAKE_SYSROOT = /opt/tdx-xwayland-upstream/6.3.0/sysroots/x86_64-tdxsdk-linux
QMAKE_SYSROOT = /opt/tdx-xwayland-upstream/6.3.0/sysroots/x86_64-tdxsdk-linux
